# S3. How to protect my storage from many files upload by authorised users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

As a part of Mobile-server application, we wanted users to upload images directly to S3 service instead of uploading them to the backend server, to alleviate the backend and make it more focused on its main function.

We did restrictive policy on AMI user (we are using one AMI user for all mobile users, is that ok?) who are allowed to upload to certain bucket, the question is: In case of stolen access and secret keys, how can I prevent the attacker from arbitrary uploading of images to fill my storage as a kind of harm to my service.

What techniques/strategies should I follow to more protect my account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon congnito is great but it was not the best fit in our case, it necessitates users to login an authentication provider (Amazon, Facebook, etc.) to be granted access to some image on S3, which we don't want to, because some of our users don't have accounts on any of those authentication providers.

Unauthorised access also is not a solution.

A better solution we came across is to use either

- [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com)
- [Filepicker](http://filepicker.com)

Where both of them allow a very smart way to let your mobile users (or web) to upload images without having credentials, they just pass signature string (some sort of tokens they get from our backend server) to be able upload any image to their site.

P.S. Both of them allow us to backup/ our images to Amazon S3.

Along with other great features, we gladly decided to use one of them.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, **never embed your Amazon Access Keys/Secret Keys in your mobile app**. If the keys are discovered/stolen, your only recourse is to revoke the tokens, but then your entire app is dead for everyone.

Instead, use Amazon Cognito to obtain temporary credentials for each user of your app.

Product info: https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/details/#credentials

Getting credentials section of the developer guide: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/getting-credentials/

Comment: Cognito is Great, yet it was not the best fit to our problem. I upvoted your answer anyway. You can check my answer below. Thanks!